# Entity framework the opposite of include

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, include

We are working on a Project in which there are many linq queries are not optimized, because as they started on the project they used the property virtual for all of their models.

My task is to optimize the max number of the queries, in order to enhance the app performance.

The problem is if I use the Include function and delete all virtual properties from the model, lot of things stop working and the number of affected functions is huge.

So I thought if I can find some thing resemble to "exclude" to exclude the unnecessary sub queries in some cases.

Comment: im aware of the diffrence but im looking for somthing more specific to exclude some sub objects for some queries not all. im looking for some thing like this : _context.Employees.Exclude(x=>x.TimeOfWorks);

Comment: `Include` is an explicit, deliberate statement to load data. The problem you describe is not about `Include`, it's *lazy loading* occurring all over the place. You could try to disable lazy loading in context instances in selected cases and fix each case separately.

Answer (score 1):

(with the assumption of your result set implements ienumerable)

My first choice would be:

```
ListMain.Except(ItemsToExclude);
```

Or, I would go with (not) "Contains" as follows and have check in-between to exclude the records. This may not be the best way out there but I could work.

```
!ListMain.Contains(ItemsToExclude)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but this happens when the query is executed and the whole result is comming and the problem not resolved because some queries are very expensive. and i want to reduce the expensivity of these queries by excluding some sub objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got the question right, but to avoid loading certain attributes or related objects, you can make an additional `Select()` including only what's needed.

Example:
A simple ToList() will bring the entire object from the table:

```
var resultList = await dbContext.ABTests.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

It will derives in the query:

```
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AssignedUsers], [a].[EndDate], [a].[Groups], [a].[Json], [a].[MaxUsers], [a].[Name], [a].[NextGroup], [a].[StartDate]
FROM [ABTests] AS [a]
```

(which includes **all** mapped fields of the `ABTest` object)

To avoid fetching all, you can do as follow:

```
var resultList = await dbContext.ABTests.AsNoTracking().Select(x => new ABTest
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name
            }).ToListAsync();
```

(supposing that you only wan the fields `Id` and `Name` to be eagerly loaded)
The resulting SQL Query will be:

```
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Name]
FROM [ABTests] AS [a]
```

Comment: This can be dangerous if not used carefully, it should preferably be used only for simple things and near the presentation layer (the final UI layer), because the object is not fully loaded and if the developer is not aware of that when using it, it is easy to introduce bugs.

Comment: A new object could be created, for example:
```
        public ABTestOnlyIdAndName(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
```

Ant then the `Select()`:
```
var resultList = await dbContext.ABTests.AsNoTracking().Select(
                    x => new ABTestOnlyIdAndName(x.Id, x.Name)
                ).ToListAsync();
```